# HWIOauthbundle with FOSUserbundle Integration error

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, hwioauthbundle

> Attempted to load class "Curl" from namespace "Buzz\Client". Did you
>   forget a "use" statement for another namespace? 500 Internal Server
>   Error - ClassNotFoundException

in app/cache/dev/appDevDebugProjectContainer.php at line 1809  -

```
protected function getHwiOauth_HttpClientService()
{
    $this->services['hwi_oauth.http_client'] = $instance = new \Buzz\Client\Curl();
    $instance->setVerifyPeer(false);
    $instance->setTimeout(10);
```

Comment: Can you run `composer install`? it may be a library not installed

Comment: Can you provide me steps to install library ? I have already added the ZIP folder in vendor folder of my symfony setup https://github.com/kriswallsmith/Buzz

Comment: Didnt get your point Please explain.

Comment: How did you install  HwiOauth Bundle? By composer? It seems you are missing the Buzz/Curl bundle, which should have been installed in the same time than HwiOauthBundle

Answer (score 0):

> When you asking a question please specify your operating system and versions of frameworks you are using (e.g. symfony 2). Here is an answer for windows and symfony2

**1) Delete manually added folders**

**2) If you don't have composer installed, install it**

- [For windows](https://getcomposer.org/Composer-Setup.exe)
- [For other read this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md)

**2) Install HWIOAuthBundle**

[HWIOAuthBundle readme.md](https://github.com/hwi/HWIOAuthBundle/blob/0.4/README.md)

*option i)  Using composer*

- Open the symfony project directory where composer.json resides.
- Open command prompt (In Windows: Shift key + Right click => open command window here)
- Run this

  composer require hwi/oauth-bundle

**OR**

*option ii) Add dependencies to your composer.json (not recomended)*

```
"require": {
    // other dependencies  will be here //
    "hwi/oauth-bundle": "^0.4.0",
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "^1.3"
}
```

then execute following command

```
composer install
```